# How do you track down JavaScript's "Unexpected token" errors when you get an irrelevant line number?

Tags: javascript, debugging, jslint, javascript-debugger

I've looked through a few questions about JavaScript reporting an unexpected token without giving a helpful line number (line 1 at localhost/index.html is "**<!DOCTYPE html>**"):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u                                      localhost:/1
```

Now I've seen a number of "Uncaught SyntaxError" posts, but I wanted to step back one meta-level and ask not just what is wrong with my current code (React JSX is at http://pastebin.com/P3Epzi0q and the HTML at http://pastebin.com/0abjnmZz is not particularly interesting), but how to best pin down what to do when dealing with an "Uncaught SyntaxError" that includes only irrelevant attribution as to where the culprit is.

My present attempt, besides using breakpoints and stepping through, is to drill down on where in my code it is happening. I am loading external sources including Showdown, jQuery, and ReactJS, but the crash is occurring between the two console.log() statements in my code:

```
  console.log("Reached 10");
  React.render(<Pragmatometer />,
    document.getElementById('main'));
  console.log("Reached 11");
```

That's still an awful lot of territory, and I am drilling down to try and see where is the last place I can place a console.log() statement that happens before the crash, and what is the earliest place I can place a console.log() statement that does not happen, just the crash.

Besides possibly more finesse with the Chrome debugger (or is that the answer?), what is the best way to tell where the issue is? Is there a linter that gives more helpful diagnostics and in particular a line number for the fault?

Maybe this question belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com, but it seems that there are repeated questions about uncaught SyntaxErrors, and the responses have pinpointed faults in code snippets but have not (so far as I have seen) explained how to pinpoint a fault when you don't have a useful line number.

Is my present vaguely binary-search-inspired use of drilling down in logging the best route? Is there something better?

Thanks,

Comment: you can use the debugger to step through the code

Comment: As @Rooster says, from what you've described, you just want to get familiar with F11 in the debugger. **"Pro" Tip:** Get an **unminified** local copy of React (and all of your other libs that you need to debug) rather than using a CDN, if you are using a CDN, and then continue debugging into, say, your `React.render();` call. Feel free to `console.log` those local files up while debugging, and then **revert to the originals when you're done**. But there's usually no *great* reason to debug with `console.log`'s when you can step through with the Chrome or Firefox (or IE, etc etc) debugger.

Comment: Quick aside: You're not looking for a linter. You should lint your code, and that might turn up an error that's causing this, sure. But if the error is happening inside of a lib, what you want is a debugger that tracks your live execution context, not a linter, which makes sure your code follows certain practices *before* it's executed.

Comment: Thanks, @all, for the suggestions. On to the debugger...

Answer (score 0):

Breadcrumb remark: I spent an hour with the debugger, partly because I did not realize that stepping-in would continue to move forward after the error was thrown.

In this case, I was acting on bad or obsolete information that localStorage[foo] would return null if nothing was saved; it was returning undefined which passed my non-null check, and JSON.parse() was throwing an exception at being fed the string "undefined".

Comment: Hm, if the error was occuring within `JSON.parse` then it should have had a stack trace. Didn't it?

Comment: `I did not realize that stepping-in would continue to move forward after the error was thrown.` It probably didn't. It should've continued iff it's caught by a `try`. Not sure what you're seeing. Btw, if your "non-null" check looks like `if (null !== obj)`, was there a reason not to simply check for [truthiness](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)? `if (obj)` That can get wacky if you have `0` or `""` (etc) in there, but you don't hit the problem you describe. But yes, if you didn't initialize to `null`, default is going to be `undefined`; alt is to check against `undefined`.